# Are ARIA roles inherited by descendants?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

In the following markup, I have a wrapper around the `<main>` element for presentational purposes.

```
<div id="main-wrapper" role="presentation">
  <main id="main" role="main">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet.</p>
  </main>
</div>
```

However I am not sure if [ARIA roles](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles) are inherited by descendants. It would be a problem if the `<main>` element is seen as presentational because the wrapper around it has `role="presentation"`.

Are the ARIA roles used correctly here? How are ARIA roles inherited?

Comment: Your main wrapper is presentational by default with no content of its own (with divs having no particular semantics) and is technically not focusable... Therefore as per your example, I don't see the need to  use role="presentation".

Comment: @hexalys Thanks, I look at it that way. So are you saying an ARIA role only applies to the direct content of an element (if any) and not to the nested elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably depends on the context and the roles. The specs and examples at:
https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#presentation give a list of "Inherited States and Properties" for each role and good examples for `role="presentation"`.

For your case, a wrapper element with `role="presentation"` will have the implicit native semantics of *all* its descendant elements *removed*. `role="main"` overrides "presentation" restoring the `<main>` semantic. But that would also mean you would have to override semantics elements within `<main>` with their respective ARIA roles, which would become extremely complicated in the context of `<main>`

But most importantly, `role="presentation"` shall only be applied to elements with an *implicit role*. `<span>` or `<div>` have no implicit roles as explained in the editor's draft with an example:

> The presentation role is used on an element that has implicit native
> semantics, meaning that there is a default accessibility API role for
> the element

```
<!-- 3. This role declaration is redundant. -->
<span role="presentation"> Sample Content </span>
```

Basically never apply `role="presentation"` to an element with no implicit native semantics, unless used *specifically* as wrapper to *remove* implicit native semantics of its descendants.